# Uninstalling netspeed indicator

Tags: uninstall, indicator

I have Ubuntu 18.04  and I installed netspeed indicator.
after change width size of this indicator.
I can't launch Ubuntu.

Now I use this code for uninstalling netspeed indicator from Shell:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
```

but it shows some errors.

Now How can I uninstall netspeed indicator?

Comment: You are purging the information of where the program can be found (the PPA). You are not purging the program name itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only removed the PPA containing the program for downloading. You need to remove the program itself:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install remove --purge indicator-netspeed
```

If that doesn't work you probably need to add back the PPA first (granted I'm not sure on this one):

```
add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt update
sudo apt install remove --purge indicator-netspeed
```